# Does Keras add any delay/overhead compared to pure TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, keras

I'm working on a project that requires object detection and recognition on images fed by a live camera.
For it to work well it should perform the evaluation for a single frame as quick as possible.

Going straight for TensorFlow instead of using Keras with TF backend will improve the performance of the whole model during the evaluation?

Comment: I tested Alexnet performance (#time/batch) with TF and Keras. I didn't see any delay with Keras. Both taking same time approx. Keras provides wrapper functions on TF. So, ideally, it should not delay.